# Unable to access attributes values in Dynamic Model validation Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-validation

I am trying to validate user input.

```
$params = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams();
$model = new DynamicModel($params);
$model->addRule(['userId', 'category', 'type'], 'required');
$model->addRule('userId', 'integer');
$model->addRule('category',
    function ($attribute, $params, $validator) use ($model) {
        var_dump($params); exit;
    });
$model->validate();
return $model;
```

How can I access the value of `category` parameter so that I can apply my validation logic. Currently its getting `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
$model->addRule(
    'category',
    function ($attribute, $params, $validator) use ($model) {
        if (empty($model->$attribute)) {
            $model->addError($attribute, 'Error message');
        }
    }
);
```

Inline validators are explained in [the guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#inline-validators).

Answer (score 0):

Correct these line below mentioned

```
$model->addRule('category',
    function ($attribute, $params, $validator) { //<---remove use($model)
        var_dump($this->$attribute); exit;  //<--- correct this line
        /*make logic here*/

    }
);
```

the closer function define here but it will call form inside of model
so that, $this->$attribute variable is working

Comment: This answer in incorrect. `$this->$attribute` will evaluate for current context (for example if you do this in controller action, `$this` will point to controller), instead of actual model.